# PHP: find biggest overlap between multiple strings

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$array = array('abc123', 'ac123', 'tbc123', '1ac123');
```

I want to compare each string to each other and find the longest common substring. In the example above the result would be `c123`.

Comment: find in what way? Get all the elemnts having c123

Comment: what you want? means $find is exist or not in your array, or indexing of $find...

Comment: In the above example you don't have that exact value anywhere. Do you simply want to know if the value exists anywhere in any value in the array?

Comment: no, I need to extract the value "c123" like it is the biggest match for all strings in array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

I've completely misunderstood the question; the aim was to find the biggest overlap between an array of strings:

```
$array = array('abc123', 'ac123', 'tbc123', '1ac123');

function overlap($a, $b)
{
        if (!strlen($b)) {
                return '';
        }

        if (strpos($a, $b) !== false) {
                return $b;
        }

        $left = overlap($a, substr($b, 1));
        $right = overlap($a, substr($b, 0, -1));

        return strlen($left) > strlen($right) ? $left : $right;
}

$biggest = null;
foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($biggest === null) {
                $biggest = $item;
        }
        if (($biggest = overlap($biggest, $item)) === '') {
                break;
        }
}

echo "Biggest match = $biggest\n";
```

I'm not great at recursion, but I believe this should work ;-)

**Old answer**

I would probably use [`preg_grep()`](http://www.php.net/preg_grep) for that; it returns an array with the matches it found based on your search string:

```
$matches = preg_grep('/' . preg_quote($find, '/') . '/', $array);
```

Alternatively, you could use `array_filter()`:

```
$matches = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($find) {
    return strpos($item, $find) !== false;
});
```

> I need to extract the value "c123" like it is the biggest match for all strings in array

I think what you would want to do here is then sort the above output based on string length (i.e. smallest string length first) and then take the first item:

```
if ($matches) {
    usort($matches,  function($a, $b) {
        return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
    });
    echo current($matches); // take first one: ac123
}
```

Let me know if I'm wrong about that.

---

If you're just after knowing whether `$find` matches an element exactly:

```
$matching_keys = array_keys($array, $find, true); // could be empty array
```

Or:

```
$matching_key = array_search($find, $array, true); // could be false
```

Or event:

```
$have_value = in_array($find, $array, true);
```

Comment: this is definetively the right answer, I didn't even know that function xD

Comment: I feel that no one understand me:
I have an array, from this array I want to compare each string and find the biggest substring which match in all strings from array, so the result as the biggest substring that matches is "c123"

Comment: @user1844923 Ahhhh! Okay, that was indeed not very clear, let me think about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
in_array($find, $array);
```

returns true if it's in the array, but it has to be the exact match, in your case it won't finde 'ac123'.

if you want to see if it contains the string then you need to loop through the array and use a preg_match() or similar

Comment: I don't have the value "c123", the question is how to find it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_filter with a callback.

```
$output = array_filter ($input, function ($elem) { return false !== strpos ($elem, 'c123'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array as used here http://codepad.org/nOdaajNe
or use can use array_search as used here http://codepad.org/DAC1bVCi

see if it can help you ..

Documentation link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array1 = array('abc123', 'ac123', 'tbc123', '1ac123');

if (in_array("c123", $array1)) {
    echo "Got c123";
}

?>
```